# AsyncPostBackTrigger is not a known element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax, visual-studio

I'm using asp.net and c#, making a page with ajax updatepanels. When I try and insert the trigger element, I get the error message *AsyncPostBackTrigger is not a known element*. What am I missing?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UdpEPL" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
    Visible="False">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnEplShowSubmit"
                EventName="BtnEplShowSubmit_Click"/>
        </Triggers>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `Triggers` section from your `ContentTemplate`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ...>
    <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger .../>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: No good. Same results. Also, I've only seen the AsyncPostBackTrigger element used under the <Triggers> section, but I also get an error message saying that capital letters aren't allowed when I use it. ??

Comment: @Brazos: The `AsyncPostBackTrigger` _should_ be within the `<Triggers>` element. Just checking the [MSDN page for UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) and other pages is seems `<Triggers>` are usually places below `<ContentTemplate>`, though, to memory, I never do that.

Comment: Ah, *facepalm, yes. I misunderstood your suggestion. Closer to functional now, thank you.